# How can I tell IntelliJ to use PHPUnit from my vendor folder?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpunit, composer-php

When I run PHPUnit from IntelliJ it seems to fall back to the PHPUnit that's installed as a pear package from my XAMPP install.

I'm not using XAMPP for this project, but I am using Composer and I dev-required the phpunit package, but the generated php file from IntelliJ doesn't seem to use that.

How can I tell IntelliJ to use PHPUnit from my vendor folder? And prevent the errors that are in the old version of pear's package.

My phpunit.xml file already contains `<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">`

Answer (score 1):

In PhpStorm (which is based on IntelliJ), you can edit this in project settings. Go to menu File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> PHP -> PHPUnit
There you need to switch to "Use custom autoloader" and put full path to your PHPUnit binary into the "Path to script" input.[image]

Comment: The only problem then is that IntelliJ doesn't recognize it and doesn't show the stats. The left pane says "Framework encountered an unexpected error"